# if and while statements in unix

Tags: sql, shell, unix

Can anyone please help me with understanding the below script from the "typeset" part in the script and what the while and if statements are doing in the script:

```
# Set effective dates for tasks
set -A EDATE `sqlplus -s / << ENDSQL
set pages 0 feed off
set timing off
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY';
select sysdate + 42, sysdate + 51, sysdate + 50 from dual;
ENDSQL`

# Check effective dates set
# ${EDATE[0]} = SYSDATE + 42 for tasks NORMALISED
# ${EDATE[1]} = SYSDATE + 51 for tasks SUBTOTAL, SUBTOTAL_RAT
# ${EDATE[2]} = SYSDATE + 50 for tasks NORMALISED_EV,CHARGE
typeset -i C=0
while [[ $C -lt 3 ]] ; do
  if [[ -z "${EDATE[C]}" ]] ; then
    echo "FAILED TO SET ROTATE PARTITION TASKS EFFECTIVE DATE! PLEASE CHECK."
    sms "${SV_SL}" "Failed to set Rotate Partition Tasks effective date. Please check."
    exit -1
  fi
  let C+=1
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line you've used builtins which is used for permit modifying the properties of variables. You can use 'declare' as well. Both are nearly equal.

In your if statement line you've included semicolon ; which isn't really required at that place. The right if..else syntax in unix is as following given.
Same for while loop also, just remove the semicolon

## If..else statement

```
x=5
y=20        
if [ $x == $y ] 
then   
echo "x is equal to y"
else
echo "x is not equal to y"
fi
```

Above code's output: x is not equal to y

## for while loop

```
a=0
while [ $u -lt 5 ]
do
echo $u
a=`expr $u + 1`
done
```

Above code's output:
0
1
2
3
4

-lt 5 indicates limits up to 5 for the while loop.

Also -z option used in if condition that is for variable or string is null.
i.e.

```
$ip="";
$[-n "$ip"] && echo "ip is not null"
$[-z "$fip"] && echo "ip is null"
```

Above code's output: ip is null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to understand the "set -A" part in the first line of the code. What does it signify?